# adding second checkbox to js function

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following function creates an `a href` link according to the user's choice of a certain checkbox called `#condition_select` (This works fine) :

```
<script>
$('.mutliSelect input:checkbox').change(function() {
var condition = $("#condition_select input:checkbox:checked").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get().join(',');

$(".submit_checkboxes").find("a").attr('href', 'index.php?condition=' + condition);
}).change();
</script>
```

What I would like to do is add a second checkbox (called `price_range`) to this function, again adding the checked values to the `a href` link.

I tried this (did not work):

```
<script>
$('.mutliSelect input:checkbox').change(function() {
var condition = $("#condition_select input:checkbox:checked").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get().join(',');

var price_range = $("#price_range_select input:checkbox:checked").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get().join(',');

$(".submit_checkboxes").find("a").attr('href', 'index.php?condition=' + condition'&price=' + price_range);
}).change();
</script>
```

Can anybody tell me where I am mistaking?
Thank you!

Comment: You left out the `+` after `+ condition`.

Comment: @Barmar: what exactly do you mean? is it supposed to be `condition=' + condition +'&price=' + price_range` ? Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: @sehetmich Yes - you're still joining the string at that point, so all portions need to be concatenated with `+`.  Also, first port of call when things don't work should be the browser dev tools (usually F12 to open).  This would have been reported as a syntax error and the exact line causing the problem highlighted

Comment: @sehetmich This is basic syntax. To concatenate strings, you have to use `+`, you can't just put them next to each other.

Comment: It seems like you already know that, since you knew to put `+` before `condition`. Why do you think it's different after the variable?

Comment: @Barmar: Thank you! I guess I was a little confused ;-)